# Randomly get an empty message in networkstream Read

Tags: c#

I am doing a multiple channels chatting project. Every time a client joins a channel, the server will broadcast the message that someone joined.

I have to make sure that the client only receives a message belonging to the channel that they are currently in.

So I did something like:

```
clientName$channelName^
clientName$JoinedChannelName^
```

I used $ and ^ to tell the program which substring is the client name and channel name.

And of course, the program needs to know how to extract the channelName when the server is broadcasting a client join event or a client message sent event, because then it can determine if the message belongs to this channel.

Things are fine but...

The broadcasting of client Joined is fine, and after I type some words that are supposed to be send to the channel and the channel broadcast it correctly. BUT SOMEHOW, the client gets another empty message on its networks stream.read.  I checked the server and it didn't do any unnecessary broadcast. The empty message isn't a big issue; it can be easily fixed, but I want to know why...Please help if you encounter similar situation before,

Here is the trouble part of the code. I cannot give the entire codes since it's awfully long...

```
string chan_name = null;
serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
int buffSize = 0;
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
MessageBox.Show("Waiting for client input");
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
MessageBox.Show("got client input");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the client gets another empty message on its networks stream.read"? NetworkStream.Read returns even if there is no data to be read and in that case the return value is 0. You should check the return value to see if it is bigger than 0 or look at the DataAvailable flag of the stream, see example in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx